# Checking if a Thread is sleeping always returns true

Tags: java, multithreading

I currently have the following problem:

I have made a 'Cache Updater Thread', which checks for updates and then sleeps for some amount of time. I have also build a `Button`, which enables the user to check for updates manually. The `Thread` is built like this:

```
public static Thread cacheUpdater = new Thread(new Runnable() {

    int milliSecondSleepTime = 10000;
    public void run() {

        try {
            cacheUpdater.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);

            //Infinite loop
            while (!terminate) {

                        syncStatus.set(0);

                //Check for updates with some methods, not important here.

                syncStatus.set(1);
                Thread.sleep(this.milliSecondSleepTime);
            }
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            //First check if it is termination time
            if (!terminate) {
                syncStatus.set(0);
                this.run();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        return;
    }

});
```

If the user clicks the manual-update button, the following code is being runned:

```
@FXML public void syncOnRequest() {

    //Only call interrupt, because then it will start again when terminate is still false
    CacheManager.cacheUpdater.interrupt();
    System.out.println(CacheManager.cacheUpdater.getState().equals(State.TIMED_WAITING));

    while (!CacheManager.cacheUpdater.getState().equals(State.TIMED_WAITING)) {
        //LOOP FOREVER
    }

    //Some code that needs to be executed after the cache is updated

}
```

I would like to continue executing code in the `syncOnRequest()` method, when the cache updater is ready with its manual update. I had the idea to check if it is sleeping, but this is not working, because the `System.out.println()` immediately returns true. I have measured the time it takes to do the update, and its between 200 and 400 ms.

**What am I doing wrong here? And why is it always returning true?**

Additional question: sometimes a click on the button just kills the `Thread`, because it just woke up. The `InterruptedException` is not thrown.

**How can I make sure the `Thread` will also restart in that case?**

Comment: I'm not totally sure what you're looking to do here. But maybe consider using "wait" instead of sleep so you can "notify" the thread when you want it to resume processing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `Thread#interrupt()` is the only polite way to ask your thread to interrupt itself (unless you explicitly implement another). Using it to restart the check is therefore a bad practice. So is checking the thread state for synchronization purposes and exposing the thread that keeps your cache up-to-date to external clients.

You manager should have a `updateCache()` method you will call directly from UI code and auto-update thread will call the same method periodically*. In that method, make sure that access to your cached data is either correctly synchronized or it happens atomically.

*) Instead of implementing your own periodic thread, consider using
[`Timer` and `TimerTask`](http://bioportal.weizmann.ac.il/course/prog2/tutorial/essential/threads/timer.html) classes as well as making it a *daemon* thread.